# Preselect a row in NSOutlineView

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

My app contains an NSOutlineView. When the user quits the app a reference to the selected row is stored in user defaults and I would like to use this to preselect the same row when they next run the app. I know the method is selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection: but I can't find out when to call it - the table is not yet populated in awakeFromNib but I don't know how I can tell when it has happened. I *really* don't want to just wait an arbitrary time - is there some notification or callback I can use?

Comment: The best moment is right after populating the data source and reloading the outline view.

Comment: Are you using an NSTreeController with your NSOutlineView ? One thing you need to consider is that you have to persist the Expand/Collapse state for your NSOutlineView as well. Without expanding the leafs before setting the selection will not work.

Comment: The data source is populated during awakeFromNib but at that point the outline view has not been set up. I'm looking for a macOS equivalent (or alternative) to viewWillAppear from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to populate the outline view in awakeFromNib and then select the row in applicationDidFinishLaunching: in the app delegate.

Comment: You can do both in *application**Will**FinishLaunching:*